# Do books have astral forms?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange

In *[Doctor Strange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange_(2016_film))*, the fight scene between Steven Strange and the zealot shows that someone's astral form has limited interaction with the physical world (only violent actions ripple into the physical world).

At the same time, one scene shows Dr. Strange learning in his astral form while his body is resting. He is holding a book:

[image]

How did that book get there? I was under the impression that the astral form is related to the spirit being pushed out of the body (and that would be it), not that there is a parallel world where every object has an astral form as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [script](https://8flix.com/assets/screenplays/m/mcu/tt1211837/Doctor-Strange-2016-screenplay.pdf) has this to say on the subject

> **WONG:** *Mr. Strange. What do you want?*
>
> **STRANGE:** *Books on Astral projection.*
>
> [snip]
>
> INT. STRANGE'S CELL - PRE-DAWN
>
> Strange ASTRAL PROJECTS while reading a book.

It's possible that the book itself has an astral form (noting that it's *literally a book about astral projection*, so being present in both realities would be a huge bonus for anyone reading it), but Strange also has the ability to [interact with physical objects while in his astral state](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=161&v=wReny0b3_ds&feature=youtu.be), so it's possible that it's just a book. We simply don't know.